# WebSphere MQ message reader (from file)

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have a message dump (binary file) from the WebSphere MQ Broker. Is there any tool I can use to open it and read message metadata (Message Descriptor, Message Header) i.e. Version, Message ID, Priority, Return Address, etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends.  What did you use to dump the messages?

The Q program from [SupportPac MA01](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMA01) will capture a queue to a file in a format that can be used to reload the messages onto the same or another queue.  The same is true of [SupportPac MO71](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMO71) (MQMon) and [SupportPac IH03](http://bit.ly/SupportPacIH03) (RFHUtil).

Similarly, there are many 3rd party products that can dump a queue to a file such as InfraRed-360, AppWatch, QPasa! and more.

If you have used one of these products to dump the queue then either the dump format should show you the message metadata or you can restore the messages to a queue and look at it there.

If by "message dump" you mean that you have copied the disk file under the queue, then the answer is no.  These files are managed by WMQ and the space is constantly being reused, reindexed and recombined.  There is no external documentation on how to parse these files.

If you are referring to the transaction logs then there are no documented formats for these either but Cressida makes a product that parses and replays the log files.